# Is there a built in method to increase the font size?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is there a built in method in bootstrap to increase the size of the text or a better way of doing it ?

```
<div class='row'>
            <div class='col-lg-12'>
                <span id='site-name-lg'> SITE NAME </span>
            </div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
#site-name-lg {
  font-size: 90px;
}
```

Comment: You could use the `h1`, `h2`, etc. classes perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use bootstrap's built in `lead` class to increase the size of text:

```
<p class="lead">SITE NAME</p>
```

However, for more flexibility over font sizes you may wish to define your own class anyway.

Bootstrap Docs: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type-body-copy